# OAuth flow when user is already logged in to the Oauth Provider

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

So, a basic OAuth2 flow using authorization grant type would normally go as follows, (assume OAuth Client=Quora, OAuth Server=Google, for eg. purposes):

1. User goes to Client, is redirected to Server sign in page for authentication.
2. User logins to Server, and Server returns an authorization_code to Client.
3. Client then makes a call with client_id, client_secret and authorization_code to Server to fetch the token.
4. Server validates and replies back with token.
5. Client can now access api/resources from Server with the token.

Now, if the user already logged in to say, Server first, then tries to access Client,

1. How will Client know that user is already logged in to Server, (as client cant access cookies from server domain)?
2. From where will the Client get the authorization code to fetch the access token?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Good question. Here's what happens:

1. Client is redirected to Server page for authorization.
2. Server (Google) has cookies set in the browser for THEIR domain only (from last time), and can see the user's information.
3. Server (Google) generates a NEW authorization code, and redirects BACK to the Client webapp with that code.
4. The Client app then makes an API call to Server with client_id, client_secret, and NEW authorization code token and gets a new access token.
5. Client app then creates a cookie (or uses local storage) to store this new Access Token and keep the user logged in.

Comment: Ha! how did I miss that. All the time I was under the impression that Client won't be able to login as it won't be redirected to the login page of the server, since already authenticated. But, the Server CAN take action by checking its cookies. Thanks! Basic stuff, but it matters.