# How to keep logged in to an OAuth2 Authentication Server?

Tags: oauth-2.0, authorization

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41769377/oauth-flow-when-user-is-already-logged-in-to-the-oauth-provider) describes how a single-page app keeps logged a user logged in with OAuth2 without using a refresh token (since a SPA can't reliably keep a refresh token secret). A critical point is that when the user's access token expires it gets another one from the authorization server, which is expected to maintain the session.

Which begs the question of how the authorization server identifies the SPA client. The linked question implies that it is invariably through a non-OAuth2 based system, such as cookies. Is that the case?

Answer (score 2):

As you have identified, SPA should not be issued with refresh token. Once OAuth flow is completed, they will receive tokens which can be either stored in a cookie or local storage (what's best between them ? Well there are many arguments for and against. I prefer local storage).

When access token get expired, you should reissue an authorization request to authorization server. This request by definition of [**OAuth protocol**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.1) include **client_id** and **redirect_url**. When the server receive the request, it will first validate these parameters to identify the validity of client. Only then it will choose to prompt for the login or use cookies to decide logged in state. This is how your SPA is identified.

Also, one important point. If your authorization server support OpenID Connect, then you can use **prompt=none** parameter in [**authorization request**](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthRequest). This is called prompt-less login which should work when authorization server has a previously logged in user cookie associated with the browser. Though this comes with OpenID Connect, depending on implementation, you may use the parameter with OAuth too.

If all mechanisms fails, unfortunately your SPA should go for a re-login.